# Service Worker termination by a timeout timer was canceled because DevTools is attached

Tags: javascript, reactjs, service-worker, sw-precache

OS: Windows 10 Pro
webpack: 1.14.0
sw-precache-webpack-plugin: 0.9.1
sw-precache: 5.0.0

So, I launch my site and don't actively do anything for a few moments, and then the above specified error message is generated in devTools. If some process is carried out, the the error does not arise

My React code is as follows:

webpack.config.prod.js

```html
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');
var SWPrecacheWebpackPlugin = require('sw-precache-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  devtool: 'source-map',
  context: __dirname,
  entry: {
    main: path.resolve(__dirname, './client/app'),
  },
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, '/public'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    publicPath: '/public/'
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': {
        'NODE_ENV': "'production'"
      }
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
      compressor: {
        warnings: false
      }
    }),
    new SWPrecacheWebpackPlugin(
      {
        cacheId: 'flamingoCity',
        filename: 'my-service-worker.js',
        stripPrefix: path.join(__dirname, 'public').replace(/\\/g,"/"),
        maximumFileSizeToCacheInBytes: 6194304,
        minify: true,
        runtimeCaching: [{
          handler: 'cacheFirst',
          urlPattern: /[.]mp3$/,
        }],
      }
    ),
  ],
  module: {
    loaders: [
    // js
    {
      test: /\.js$/,
      loaders: ['babel'],
      include: path.join(__dirname, 'client')
    },
    // CSS
    { 
      test: /\.styl$/, 
      include: path.join(__dirname, 'client'),
      loader: 'style-loader!css-loader!stylus-loader'
    }
    ]
  }
};
```

app.js

```html
/*
  Import Dependencies
*/
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { Router, Route, IndexRoute } from 'react-router'
import 'babel-polyfill';

/*
  Import Components
*/
import App from './components/App';
import Single from './components/Single';
import PhotoGrid from './components/PhotoGrid';

/* Import CSS */
import css from  './styles/style.styl';

/* Import our data store */
import store, { history } from './store';

/*
  Error Logging
*/

import Raven from 'raven-js';
import { sentry_url } from './data/config';
if(window) {
  Raven.config(sentry_url).install();
}

/*
  Register Service Worker
*/

if('serviceWorker' in navigator  && process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  navigator.serviceWorker.register('./my-service-worker.js').then(function(reg) {
  // updatefound is fired if my-service-worker.js changes.
  reg.onupdatefound = function() {
    // The updatefound event implies that reg.installing is set; see
    // https://slightlyoff.github.io/ServiceWorker/spec/service_worker/index.html#service-worker-container-updatefound-event
    var installingWorker = reg.installing;

    installingWorker.onstatechange = function() {
      switch (installingWorker.state) {
        case 'installed':
          if (navigator.serviceWorker.controller) {
            // At this point, the old content will have been purged and the fresh content will
            // have been added to the cache.
            // It's the perfect time to display a "New content is available; please refresh."
            // message in the page's interface.
            console.log('New or updated content is available.');
          } else {
            // At this point, everything has been precached.
            // It's the perfect time to display a "Content is cached for offline use." message.
            console.log('Content is now available offline!');
          }
          break;

        case 'redundant':
          console.error('The installing service worker became redundant.');
          break;
      }
    };
  };
  }).catch(function(e) {
    console.error('Error during service worker registration:', e);
  });
}

/*
  Rendering
  This is where we hook up the Store with our actual component and the router
*/
render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    { /* Tell the Router to use our enhanced history */ }
    <Router history={history}>
      <Route path="/" component={App}>
        <IndexRoute component={PhotoGrid} />
        <Route path="/view/:postId" component={Single}></Route>
      </Route>
    </Router>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

What is the issue here?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Normally, idle service workers are aggressively killed as an optimization, to prevent code from running in the background when it's not needed.

Chrome takes steps to detect whether DevTools are open, and when it is, will not kill the service worker automatically. The assumption is that if a developer is using DevTools, they might be debugging or otherwise examining the service worker's behavior, and killing the service worker would frustrate the developer.

Extending the lifetime of the service worker used to be done silently, but [as described here](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/chromium-reviews/xVXklMLtekY), for the past few versions of Chrome, the message

> Service Worker termination by a timeout timer was canceled because
>   DevTools is attached.

is logged to the console to let the developer know that the service worker would normally have been killed, but the job to kill it was cancelled due to DevTools being open.

You might ask, what difference does that make? Why bother letting the developer know that something *didn't* happen?

The motivation for pointing this out is to let the developer know that something that real users will encounter in production (i.e. the service worker being repeatedly killed/restarted) is not happening in this debugging environment. This makes a difference if a developer has written buggy service worker code that makes [incorrect assumptions about the persistence of global state](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38835274/385997).  It's easy to write code that assumes global state will always persist, and works when run with DevTools open (because the service worker is never killed), and then fails to work in production.

Comment: Really good that they added this message :- ) Now I found this topic, and the other topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38835273/when-does-code-in-a-service-worker-outside-of-an-event-handler-run/38835274#38835274 — which will save me lots of time, maybe days: *"In general, code that's outside any event handler, in the "top-level" of the service worker's global scope, will run each and every time the service worker thread(/process) is started up  ..."*

Answer (score 0):

```html
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');
var SWPrecacheWebpackPlugin = require('sw-precache-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  devtool: 'source-map',
  context: __dirname,
  entry: {
    main: path.resolve(__dirname, './client/app'),
  },
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, '/public'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    publicPath: '/public/'
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': {
        'NODE_ENV': "'production'"
      }
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
      compressor: {
        warnings: false
      }
    }),
    new SWPrecacheWebpackPlugin(
      {
        cacheId: 'flamingoCity',
        filename: 'my-service-worker.js',
        stripPrefix: path.join(__dirname, 'public').replace(/\\/g,"/"),
        maximumFileSizeToCacheInBytes: 6194304,
        minify: true,
        runtimeCaching: [{
          handler: 'cacheFirst',
          urlPattern: /[.]mp3$/,
        }],
      }
    ),
  ],
  module: {
    loaders: [
    // js
    {
      test: /\.js$/,
      loaders: ['babel'],
      include: path.join(__dirname, 'client')
    },
    // CSS
    { 
      test: /\.styl$/, 
      include: path.join(__dirname, 'client'),
      loader: 'style-loader!css-loader!stylus-loader'
    }
    ]
  }
};
```

Comment: Hi, while your code may contain a solution to the problem, it would be helpful if you included a description of your code (and include some comments) and highlight important snippets to help others understand your answer.