# How to make a service-worker.js to excecute on browser open?

Tags: javascript, push-notification, service-worker

Hello i have installed a service worker but it works only when i open the page here's the code

```
self.addEventListener('install', function(event) {
  console.log('service worker online')
});
```

on install it prits that `service worker online` but my question is how can i make it work even if the page is not open

I would like to use it to send browser notifications such as

[image]
on browser open just like facebook does

Answer (score 1):

There's information about adding push notification support to a web app at https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/codelabs/push-notifications/

One approach, if you're not already tied to a given push messaging provider, is to use [Firebase Cloud Messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/client), which ships with a library to simplify implementing your service worker's push handler.

In general, if you're curious about when various bits of code inside your service worker actually execute, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38835274/385997) might be helpful. You do need to implement push notifications in a service worker to get the behavior you describe.