# Using JS serviceWorker as identity proxy - trying to detect `access_token` unregister

Tags: javascript, oauth-2.0, single-page-application, service-worker

I am evaluating using a JS ServiceWorkers as an identity proxy, injecting the `access_token` on `fetch()` calls.

```js
const addAuthHeader = function (event) {
    destURL = new URL(event.request.url);
    if (whitelistedOrigins.includes(destURL.origin) && whitelistedPathRegex.test(destURL.pathname)) {
        const modifiedHeaders = new Headers(event.request.headers);
        if (token) {
           modifiedHeaders.append('Authorization', token) //< Injection
        }
        const authReq = new Request(event.request, {headers: modifiedHeaders, mode: 'cors' });
        event.respondWith((async () => fetch(authReq))());
    }
}

// Intercept all fetch requests and add the auth header
self.addEventListener('fetch', addAuthHeader);
```

The `token` is stored in a closure variable within the serviceWorker class. [Click here](https://blog.ropnop.com/storing-tokens-in-browser/#service-worker) for more information about this approach.

One problem I am running into is that when the serviceWorker is updated, the `token` variable is being overwritten and the `access_token` is lost.

Is there a way to detect that the serviceWorker has been updated? Or, to protect the `token` variable? Is there a design pattern/standard you can point me towards related to using serviceWorker as an identity proxy as I have done?

Answer (score 0):

I would advise against an approach that requires a service worker to be in control of a given page for anything security/identity related.

First off, users who visit your page for the first time will not have a service worker installed yet, so it won't be in control of the current page. Additionally, users who are familiar with the browser's developer tools can unregister a service worker at any time, and/or use shift-reload to visit your page without the active service worker in control. So you really can't rely on the service worker always being there.

Second, a service worker's global state is short-lived, and you can't rely on variables being present across multiple event invocations. There are more details about that in "[When does code in a service worker outside of an event handler run?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38835274/385997)".

Generally speaking, you should consider the behavior inside of a service worker as progressively enhancing the core functionality of your web app, and not move any required functionality to the service worker.

Comment: What are your thoughts on the **Closure Variable** option, then?

https://blog.ropnop.com/storing-tokens-in-browser/#closure-variable

Comment: Storing an in-memory value inside of a closure doesn't change any of the things to keep in mind about service worker best practices.

Comment: How do you normally store the `access_token` you receive back from your OAuth2 flow?

Comment: I don't have experience with that in the context of a PWA.